# How to handle nested JSON object request in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

We had this webservice running in Laravel 5 and AngularJs/Ionic for handling the web. When we post request from the web (client) to webservice (backend), we passed nested JSON object. We are having an issue to read all child objects under parent object in the server side.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "startdate": "2016-02-21T13:00:00.000Z",
    "enddate": "2016-02-23T13:00:00.000Z",
    "coach": {
        "uuid": "76fdd664-d830-11e5-9d46-00ffc9587cbc"
    },
    "category": {
        "uuid": "771e6de4-d830-11e5-9d46-00ffc9587cbc"
    },
    "useruuid": "76d65a2d-d830-11e5-9d46-00ffc9587cbc",
    "routines": ["775b2726-d830-11e5-9d46-00ffc9587cbc"]
}
```

This JSON has been verified ok and I also we managed to get the basic one such as name, endate etc etc BUT not the nested object one.

We are using something like this in Laravel 5:

```
$incomingdata = $request->json()->all();
$name = $incomingdata->name; // works
$startdate = $incomingdata->startdate; // works
$coach_uuid = $incomingdata->coach()->uuid; // didn't work !!!
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty confused about what's going on here. So does the client send the JSON to the server?

Comment: @OliverQueen : Correct! Client sent JSON data with nested object to the server running on Laravel 5.

Comment: Okay, I'd definitely suggest using `json_decode()`

Comment: @OliverQueen : I made adjustments on my question to make it clear.

Comment: what does `print_r($incomingdata);` return?

Comment: It should probably be `$incomingdata->coach->uuid` (notice: no parentheses on `coach`). If that's a typo in your question, then you could try `$incomingdata->coach[ 'uuid' ]`.

Comment: @OliverQueen : Due to the code is in webservice, so I have to log in Laravel so become: Log::info('Print:' . print_r($data)); but the return value is 1. That is it - no detail info !!!

Comment: @DecentDabbler : I have to do something like this in order to work: $coach_uuid = $incomingdata['coach']['uuid'];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonObject,true);
$name = $phpArray['name'];
$coach = $phpArray['coach'];
$coach_uuid = $phpArray['coach']['uuid'];
$category = $phpArray['category']; 
$category_uuid = $phpArray['category']['uuid];
```

Comment: In Laravel 5, there is a method to convert: using $request->json()->all(); and so $data = $request->json()->all(); and I can access easily via $data->name or $data->enddate BUT not the nested object $data->coach->uuid or $data->category->uuid

Comment: I have to do something like this in order to work: $coach_uuid = $incomingdata['coach']['uuid'];  Thanks !!! I thought there is elegent way in Laravel to achieve this :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about Laravel 5.0, but in Laravel 5.6 I had to do something quite different. None of the code in other answers worked for me.

Here is what I found to work correctly:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
$startdate = $request->input('startdate');
$coach_uuid = $request->input('coach.uuid');
print_r($name.'<br />');
print_r($startdate.'<br />');
print_r($coach_uuid.'<br />');
```

The above prints:

```
test
2016-02-21T13:00:00.000Z
76fdd664-d830-11e5-9d46-00ffc9587cbc
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input